# For every row, loop through every column that has a value with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where every row may have different numbers of columns.
[example of my df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewPgb.png)

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
row1    2   4   5           
row2    3   4   5   6       
row3    1   2   4   6       
row4    2   3   5   7   8   
row5    1   2   4   5   6   
row6    2   3   4   7   8   9
row7    2   3   5   6   7   9
row8    3   4   6   8   9   
row9    2   4   5   7   9   10
row10   4   7   6   9       
row11   3   6   7   8   10  9
row12   4   6   8   9   11  
row13   4   5   7   10  9   11
row14   5   6   9   11  10  12
```

For every row, how can I loop through every column **that has a value** with pandas?

Something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     #for every column that has a value
          #do something with this column value of this row
```

Thanks

Comment: dont iterate over a dataframe whenever possible , check this out for reference how you can assign values conditionally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Comment: what's a value, anything that's not a blank string?

Comment: In this case, i'm referring to value as a string or number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad practice, but you can just make another for loop with a mask that removes `nan` values. You were almost there:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for value in row[row.notnull()]:
        print(value)
```

It's bad practice because `pandas` supports vectorized operations, so there's almost always a way to do your operation without a loop.

Comment: you could just replace the blank strings with `np.nan` then use `isnull()` and specify the axis and use`.loc` for any boolean assignment